# Проблемы с фокусом при нажатии на Enter в EditText

Tags: java, android

Когда тыкаю на Enter в EditText, выбирается "следующим" неправильное поле(

**Программа минимум**: как запретить ставить фокус на другой EditText, когда нажимаешь на Enter?

**Программа максимум**: как переписать дефолтный код, чтобы при нажатии на Enter выбирался для фокуса тот EditText, который я хочу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет android:nextFocusDown
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android%3anextFocusDown

> Defines the next view to give focus to when the next focus is
>   View.FOCUS_DOWN If the reference refers to a view that does not exist
>   or is part of a hierarchy that is invisible, a RuntimeException will
>   result when the reference is accessed.